# Merge and where clause not working properly in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe

I am new to Python pandas,

I have been trying to join two dataframe's and after join want to put where clause. I tried below ways which gave me two different results. I understand filtering out the data before merge/join is recommended. but there are few things I want to accomplish with where clause after join. I don't understand how sequence of where clause can change the output. request you to please help me in understanding.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Table1 = pd.DataFrame({'student_name': ['Ram','Sham','kane','jhon','hari','mari','khari','rob'],
                       'studemt_id': [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008],
                       'subject': ['maths','science','history','history','science','maths','maths','science'],
                       'mark': [56,48,98,56,98,34,67,87],
                       'teacher': ['agon','visyres','denarys','denarys','nead','demon','agon','visyres'],
                       'roll_number': ['X','IX','VII','X','IX','VII','X','IX']})

Table2 = pd.DataFrame({'teacher': ['agon','visyres','denarys','nead','demon'],
                       'teacher_id': [101,102,103,104,105],
                       'subject': ['maths','science','history','science','maths'],
                       'classroom': ['X','IX','VII','X','IX','VII']})
```

Way-1[which worked for me  ]:

```
 t3= Table1.merge(Table2.where(Table2["classroom"]=="X"), how="right",on=["subject" ,"teacher"])
 t3[t3['classroom'].notna()]
```

Result:

```
    student_name    studemt_id  subject mark    teacher roll_number teacher_id  classroom
0   Ram                 1001.0          maths       56.0    agon    X   101.0   X
1   khari               1007.0          maths      67.0     agon    X   101.0   X
```

way-2 :

```
  t3= Table1.merge(Table2, how="right",on=["subject" ,"teacher"]).where(Table2["classroom"]=="X")
  print(t3[t3['classroom'].notna()])
```

Result:

```
    student_name    studemt_id  subject mark    teacher roll_number teacher_id  classroom
0   Ram              1001.0     maths   56.0    agon    X                101.0  X`
```

Comment: Do you want to understand, why way-1 and 2 are not having the same results?

Answer (score 0):

In your `way-2`, you are trying to filter merged dataframe with `Table2`'s indexes, so there is miss match in the output's.

And pandas's [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method is not same as SQL's `where` condition.

**Modified way-2:**

```
t3 = Table1.merge(Table2, how="right",on=["subject" ,"teacher"])
t3 = t3.where(t3["classroom"]=="X")
print(t3[t3['classroom'].notna()])
```

**Output:**

```
|    | student_name   |   studemt_id | subject   |   mark | teacher   | roll_number   |   teacher_id | classroom   |
|---:|:---------------|-------------:|:----------|-------:|:----------|:--------------|-------------:|:------------|
|  0 | Ram            |         1001 | maths     |     56 | agon      | X             |          101 | X           |
|  1 | khari          |         1007 | maths     |     67 | agon      | X             |          101 | X           |
|  6 | hari           |         1005 | science   |     98 | nead      | IX            |          104 | X           |
```

I'm getting the same output for the `way-1` as well.

**Data:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

Table1 = pd.DataFrame({'student_name': ['Ram','Sham','kane','jhon','hari','mari','khari','rob'],
                       'studemt_id': [1001,1002,1003,1004,1005,1006,1007,1008],
                       'subject': ['maths','science','history','history','science','maths','maths','science'],
                       'mark': [56,48,98,56,98,34,67,87],
                       'teacher': ['agon','visyres','denarys','denarys','nead','demon','agon','visyres'],
                       'roll_number': ['X','IX','VII','X','IX','VII','X','IX']})

Table2 = pd.DataFrame({'teacher': ['agon','visyres','denarys','nead','demon'],
                       'teacher_id': [101,102,103,104,105],
                       'subject': ['maths','science','history','science','maths'],
                       'classroom': ['X','IX','VII','X','IX']})
```

Note: OP's provided output is not matching with provided data in post.